# Single on/off checkbox default value not work

Tags: 7, entities

I have a boolean user profile field which is single on/off checkbox, says 'field_user_flag'. Its **On** value is 1 and **Off** value is 0. But I could not set `#default_value = 1` from `hook_form_alter` to save "1" into its table `field_data_field_user_flag` and `field_revision_field_user_flag`.

When it is 0 and unchecked in user/*/edit, I would like to set it to 1 and checked. Thus, I did it in my hook_form_alter as below.

```
$form['field_user_flag']['#default_value'] = 1;
$form['field_user_flag']['#attributes'] = array('checked' => 'checked');
```

But, it did not work. I created the field in account settings (admin/config/people/accounts/fields/) without using [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

Comment: where the field axactly in your usera ccount or created with porfile2 module?

Comment: I created the field in account settings (admin/config/people/accounts/fields/) without using profile2 module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested it and worked for me:

```
$form['field_user_flag'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = 1;
```

You can also set a default value of this field (in field settings in field managment).

Comment: @SithuKyaw , your welcome. I am glad can help you.

Comment: it's best practice to use [LANGUAGE_NONE] rather than ['und'] https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7.x or [LANGUAGE_NOT_SPECIFIED] in drupal8